# java ejb java.rmi.UnknownHostException

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I am debugging a swing application with java ejb beans.

When I launch main swing application, I generate a context

```
Hashtable<String,String> environment = new Hashtable<String,String>();
environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, FACTORY);
environment.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, PKG);
environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://11.11.111.11:1099");
Context context = new InitialContext(environment);
classService= (classService) context.lookup("emprise_j2ee_application/ClassService/remote");
```

Now I have a exception:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: subdomain.domain.com; nested exception is: 
    java.net.UnknownHostException: subdomian.domain.com]
```

I don´t understand the exception becuase I see inside the Context var the ip and not the domain that show the exception.

Where is cached the domain and who I can change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error is in the server that I try connect.

The server have in her config connect with this domain and when my app try connect and the server don´t leave me connect. I get the error with the domain that have in the configuration.